# Lighter alternative to tensorflow-python for distribution

Tags: python, tensorflow, deployment, pyinstaller, predict

I was trying to compile a py file to binary that simply reads the model from a json file and predicts the output via the imported model.
Now the issue is that when I try to compile the program through pyinstaller the resulting file is around 290mb as it tries to compile the whole tensorflow package and it unwanted dependencies. Not to mention that it is very very slow to start up as tries to extract the files.

As you can see it is just a simple code that runs through a folder of images and identifies them as either a meme or a non meme content to clean my whatsapp folder.

```py
import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator 
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
import shutil

BATCH_SIZE = 8
SHAPE = (150,150,3)

p = input("Enter path of folder to extract memes from")
p = p.replace("'","")
p = p.replace('"','')

json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model.load_weights('weights.best.hdf5')
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        p,
        target_size=SHAPE[:-1],
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        class_mode=None,
        shuffle=False)

pred = model.predict_generator(generator)
# print(pred)
# print(model.summary())
pred[pred>0.5] = 1
pred[pred<=0.5] = 0
d = ["garbage","good"]
for i in range(len(pred)):
  filename = generator.filenames[i].split('\\')[1]
  if(pred[i][0] == 0):
    shutil.move(generator.filepaths[i],os.path.join(os.path.join('test',str(int(pred[i][0]))),filename))
```

So my question is that, is there an alternative to the model.predict function that may be a lot lighter than the one tensorflow has as I do not want to include the whole 600mb tensorflow package in my distribution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use quantization on your Tensorflow models? Model size can be reduced to 75%. This is the processing that enables Tensorflow Lite to make predictions on pictures in real-time, on nothing more than a mobile phone CPU.

Essentially, weights can be converted to types with reduced precision, such as 16 bit floats or 8 bit integers. Tensorflow generally recommends 16-bit floats for GPU acceleration and 8-bit integer for CPU execution. Read the [guide here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization).

> Quantization brings improvements via model compression and latency reduction. With the API defaults, the model size shrinks by 4x, and we typically see between 1.5 - 4x improvements in CPU latency in the tested backends. Eventually, latency improvements can be seen on compatible machine learning accelerators, such as the EdgeTPU and NNAPI.
>
> Post-training quantization includes general techniques to reduce CPU and hardware accelerator latency, processing, power, and model size with little degradation in model accuracy. These techniques can be performed on an already-trained float TensorFlow model and applied during TensorFlow Lite conversion.

Read more about post-training [model quantization here](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/quantization/post_training).

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry for being a little vague. The issue is not with the model or the weights. Though it is a good strategy to further compress the model. I was hoping for an alternative to tensorflow that only reads and predicts from the saved weights. Because after running pyinstaller, the program tries to compress the whole tensorflow package and all its unnecessary dependacies. I Don't want that to happen

Comment: This is literally what I'm saying. Tensorflow Lite is a tiny version of Tensorflow that only reads the reduced models and makes predictions. But I'm talking about quantization because Tensorflow Lite doesn't read full models, it reads reduced models.